# Asking for a char*

Tags: c++, pointers

Is there a way to do something like this :

```
void test(char *userInput){ 
  //code
} 
char userInput = "test"; 
test(userInput);
```

I have the error : `Process finished with exit code 139` so how can i proceed ?

Comment: `char userInput = "test";`  this is probably not what you wanted to write. Consider `char userInput[] = "test";`

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Prefer `std::string` over `char*`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to do something like this :

Sure, just change your code a bit:

```
void test(const char *userInput){ 
   //code
} 

int main() {
    const char* userInput = "test"; 

    test(userInput); 
}
```

> I have the error : `Process finished with exit code 139` so how can i proceed?

I'm pretty sure the compiler did show you some [further errors](http://ideone.com/drCgzl) before this one came up. Fix these first.

Answer (score 1):

You marked this as a C++ question ... std::strings are very easy to use.

```
// NOTE: userinput can be either std::string OR const char*
void test(std::string userinput)
{
   // code, perhaps echo testing input
   std::cout << userinput << std::endl;
}

// test 290 - invoked somewhere in main
int t290(void)
{
   std::string userInput = "test1";
   test(userInput);

   // some times you can save some typing
   test("test2");     // function declared as above
                      // accepts both const char* or std::string

   return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As other people pointed out, there's an error in your code, `char` should be changed to `const char*`. Char only holds one value, not the entire string, and if your function takes a const value the string has also to be. Also, given you're using C++, you can use `std::string` wich is really straightforward to use.